Kafka process batch data per partition
I have a Kafka topic with thousands of partitions (each partition containing data from a particular user) and need to process the data efficiently. My goal is to trigger an AWS Lambda function when 20 messages accumulate in a partition (essentially 20 messages for a user). Is it possible to configure Lambda to process messages in batches per partition, rather than usual batching at the topic level? If not what should be that possible approach to process the data in batches for each user?

I'm not sure about lambda, but Kafka consumers default to poll 500 records, by default. If your consumer group has the size of the topic partitions, then that's 500 per partition

My concern is how to process data in batches from a specific partition. Typically, when you add a trigger to process something like lambda functions, it activates after batches are formed from a topic, which may have messages from multiple partitions. If, instead of creating one topic with multiple partitions, we choose to create multiple topics with a single partition each, how can we set up a trigger to process the data? Especially considering that the topics won't be predefined hence is dynamic.

Kafka consumers also support regex patterns for that use case. Again, I'm not familiar with lambda configurations , but if it doesn't support your needs, then you can run consumers in ECS instead

According to this blog lambda can scale up to the number of partitions, based on consumer lag, as needed, otherwise it'll batch up to 6MB of data at a time (lambda event max) or 100 records (default batch size).

Lambda allocates processors across all pollers based on the number of partitions up to a maximum of one concurrent Lambda function per partition. You can increase the number of processing Lambda functions by increasing the number of partitions

Otherwise, you can iterate over the event structure, and parse the topic, partition, and offset keys and sort them into individual lists, by increasing order of offset, then process each list separately from iterating the batch directly from the initial event.
All records are always ordered by offset. But you're not guaranteed to get at least 20 records per partition in any single event.
If that's a hard requirement, you'll need a preprocessing consumer that can produce windowed events with lists of 20 events per partition, or aggregate data downstream such as in Dynamo and wait for it to collect 20 values for a given key before processing that event further. For example (untested)
from collections import defaultdict

bucket = defaultdict(list)
records = event["records"]
for tp, messages in records.items():
    # lookup previously accumulated records
    bucket[tp].extend(restore(tp)) 
    # TODO: handle at-least once delivery duplication 
    bucket[tp].extend(messages)

    if len(bucket[tp]) >= 20:
        # TODO: consider sorting by offset first 
        bucket[tp] = process_messages(bucket[tp])  # return remainder, less than 20

    if bucket[tp]:
        # persist smaller batches  
        save(tp, bucket[tp])
        del bucket[tp]

